# How to implement real-time live messaging jQuery Ajax Mysql Php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, websocket, long-polling

I'm writting a very simple chat application. I have written a code that works at inserting data in database without refreshing the page. But when I test with two users at the same time, I can only see what the other user sent to me when I send a new message. How can I make it more live? I spent the entire day reading on Websockets (specifically socket.io, ratchet) and long-polling. I found interesting solutions around here but I'm looking to implement it with the code I have already written and it's confusing me. I'm using a php while statement to get data from database.

**Working Ajax code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttons").click(function(){
var fromuserid = $("#fromUserId").val();
var touserid = $("#toUserId").val();
var chatMessage = $("#chatMessage").val();
// stored in database.
var dataString = 'fromUserId='+ fromuserid + '&toUserId='+ touserid + '&chatMessage='+ chatMessage;
// AJAX
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "chat.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(response){
   $("#displayMessage").html(response);
       $("#chatForm").trigger("reset");
}
});

return false;
});
});
    </script>
```

**while statement**

```
       <div id='displayMessage' style='height: 480px; padding:5%; overflow-x:hidden;'>
        <?php
            $chatmsgQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c 
   WHERE c.isActive='1' AND (c.fromUserId='$loginid_session' 
   OR c.toUserId='$loginid_session')";
$chatmsgresult=  mysqli_query($db,$chatmsgQ);
        while($chatmsg=  mysqli_fetch_array($chatmsgresult)){?>
   <?php if($chatmsg['fromUserId']==$loginid_session):?>
   <!-- user one -->
<p class='bubble pull-left'><?=$chatmsg['message'];?></p>
<?php elseif($chatmsg['fromUserId']!=$loginid_session):?>
  <!-- user two-->
<p class='bubbleother pull-right'><?=$chatmsg['message'];?></p>
<?php endif;?>
<?php } ;?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show the table schemas involved in the query. Are you sure you're retrieving messages from both users? Does the query work in phpMyAdmin (or similar)?

Answer (score 2):

PHP isn't really the best language to use when it comes to push messages, it's really built around typical get/response kinda flows.

[http://www.nodejs.org](http://www.nodejs.org/) and  http://socket.io/hey're very easy to get setup, and will play well with you using php for the majority of your work, then using node to deal with push messages kinda stuff.

Comment: Node.js will mess up with my ports and I suspect it will slow me down at this point ?

Comment: node.js and php are going to be two independent processes, and so you can't just call stuff between them, nor can you call node.js function on your client side.

Answer (score 1):

To make your application more live, you need to use 
`setInterval` method. Use this project [Simple php, ajax and mysql chat application.](https://github.com/mahfuzak08/simple_chat)

Comment: Nice project man. It seems to be what I need to do. Would you mind teaching by example with my codes? No need to be too complex just a working snippet. I tried adding    `window.setInterval(function() {    
     $("#displayMessage").load("chat.php");

  }, 2000);` but it gives me undefined index

Comment: Sorry for late. I'll upload example soon. And if this is good answer, then accept it.